# Output days since nth event

Tags: firebird

I have a table `Events` in a Firebird database (version 3.0.8) that records how many times an event occurs. Example below:

| Date | EventCount |
| --- | --- |
| 22-04-01 | 15 |
| 22-09-30 | 10 |
| 22-10-01 | 1 |
| 22-10-04 | 1 |

I would like to create a query to output the number of days from today since the nth event occurred (`n` being manually set in the code, not a end-user variable).

For example, if I wanted the number of days since the 13th event, the output should be the `DATEDIFF` of today and `22-04-01`. If I wanted days since the 3rd event, the query would use `22-09-30`

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Surely the 3rd event is on 22-04-01? Also, which version of Firebird?

Comment: @Vérace I'm not too sure. I've been using Libreoffice Base 7.4.2.3 as the front end, but up until recently I've been on HSQLDB. With it deprecated, I've migrated to Firebird and have been learning the syntax differences. Is there a direct command to print the version? As for the 3rd event, the first event from the date the query is run on would be `22-10-04`. Second event on `22-10-01`. Third to twelfth events all on `22-09-30`.

Comment: It's a  bit of a mouthful compared to other systems - `SELECT rdb$get_context('SYSTEM', 'ENGINE_VERSION') as version from rdb$database;` - assuming you have access to an `isql` like tool!

Comment: @Vérace it certainly is! The version is 3.0.8.

Comment: OK - so explain to me why the 3rd event isn't on `22-04-01` - i.e. within the first 15?

Comment: @Vérace the intention is not to select the third event from the oldest date (ie, the third oldest event), but to work backwards from today's current date. I'd like to select the third newest event, then calculate the DATEDIFF of today and that date.

Comment: OK - I see now. I'll have a look in the morning!

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: [Count days since 3rd event from today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74262830/count-days-since-3rd-event-from-today)

Answer (score 0):

This is a repost from [my answer to the cross-site duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74264847/466862). I'm posting it here for completeness.

---

You can use the `SUM` [window function](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref30/firebird-30-language-reference.html#fblangref30-windowfuncs) to calculate a running total, and then find which row has the first equal or higher running total. Then you can use `datediff` (in my example I switched the position of `current_date` because I liked it better for the name I gave my column - `days_ago`):

```sql
select 
  event_date,
  event_count,
  event_count_running_total,
  datediff(day, event_date, current_date) days_ago
from (
  select 
    event_date, 
    event_count, 
    sum(event_count) over (order by event_date desc) event_count_running_total
  from events
)
where event_count_running_total >= 3
order by event_date desc
fetch first row only
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/bGwQtI2v

With Firebird 4.0, using [window frames](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#fblangref40-windowfuncs-frame) would allow for a (slightly) different solution:

```sql
select 
  event_date,
  event_count,
  event_count_running_total,
  event_count_running_prev,
  datediff(day, event_date, current_date) days_ago
from (
  select 
    event_date, 
    event_count, 
    sum(event_count) over (order by event_date desc) event_count_running_total, 
    sum(event_count) over (order by event_date desc rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) event_count_running_prev
  from events
)
where 3 between event_count_running_prev and event_count_running_total
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/r9q0nmHj